# Drawing directed graph in Latex

Tags: graph, latex

I want to draw an arrow from A pointing to B, C, D..as in the drawing. How do I do that in Latex.

So far, I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](z){$A$}
  child{node[circle,draw]{B}} 
  child{node[circle,draw]{C}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{D}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{E}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{F}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{G}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

nvm, I figure it out.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}]
\node[circle,draw](z){$A$}
  child{node[circle,draw]{B}} 
  child{node[circle,draw]{C}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{D}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{E}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{F}}
  child{node[circle,draw]{G}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```